# How do I replace the user input in text box as it is being typed

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox where I need to replace the user input with an int from 0 to 1 for each letter typed, so typing "hello world" for example would result in a number like "01011010100". My code so far is:

```
textbox.addEventListener("beforeinput", function() {
    textbox.value = textbox.value.replace(/\D+/g, findRandom());
}, false);
```

where findRandom() is a function that gives the random integer, and it works ok for the most part, however it does not consider the last letter typed, and using a keydown listener has too much of a lag between the letter being inputted and it being replaced. How do I make it so that no matter what the user types it comes out as 1 or 0 fast enough that they don't see what they actually typed?

Comment: What about [oninput event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) ?

Comment: @MariusROBERT Oh, huh, I'm a beginner so I didn't know that existed, thanks, you've solved it

Comment: Can you please insert code of your findRandom method?

Comment: @aca the problem's been solved by MariusROBERT, thank you for wanting to help, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the oninput property instead of a beforeinput listener.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).